# Replacing multiple controllers with one (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I've designed a several GUI's using Gloun SceneBuilder
Which means each and every GUI form will have its own contoller
For Example: AddBookForm.fxml will have AddBookController.java

```
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class AddBookController {

    @FXML
    private Button btnAddBook;

    @FXML
    void AddBook(MouseEvent event) {

    }

}
```

EditBookForm.fxml will have EditBookController

```
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class PleaseProvideControllerClassName {

    @FXML
    private Button btnEditBook;

    @FXML
    void editBook(MouseEvent event) {

    }

}
```

So I would like to have both of the GUI's controllers into one, one I'd name BookController (It would have AddBook and EditBook button handlers)
So all books events would be into one controller instead of separate ones
Is that possible? and if so, how?
\I saw that it could be related to lambda, but I really don't get it..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not entirely clear what you are asking - please consider giving an example of what you tried or how you approached the problem, and the concrete place where you got stuck. You may also want to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @J.A.P but I would be having too much controllers for same category functions, is it possible to group all of them into one place?

Comment: Another option would be to have an abstract controller that provides the common functionality. Then each FXML file's specific controller would extend the abstract controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple set the same controller to the two `fxml` files <sup>1</sup> :

**A.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="buttonA" onAction="#buttonAClicked" text="A" textAlignment="CENTER" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

**B.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="src.tests.xml.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="buttonB" onAction="#buttonBClicked" text="B" textAlignment="CENTER" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

**Controller.java** (used by both)

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller{

    @FXML
    private Button buttonA, buttonB;

    public void buttonAClicked(){
        System.out.println("Button A clicked");
    }

    public void buttonBClicked(){
        System.out.println("Button B clicked");
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> 
Each `fxml` uses a different instance of `Controller` so it is **not** a shared one

Comment: while technically true, it's a path into certain (sooner or later ;) NPEs - depending on which fxml is loaded, the other button is null .. if you really really really want that single controller encapsulating several actions, at least don't expose the triggering buttons as fields.